# Display flex even space between children regardless of children width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two instances of the same row-component that has `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`:

```
<div class="component-row">
  <div>looooooooooong</div>
  <div>short</div>
  <div>mediummm</div>
</div>

<div class="component-row">
  <div>looooooooooong</div>
  <div>short</div>
  <div>mediummm</div>
</div>
```

The spacing between the children of each component will be different because the children have different widths. Without changing the order of the children, how can I make sure that both component instances have the same amount of space between each of their children? Within the instance, the space (ex. the space between long and short) doesn't have to be equal - what I want is the space between the 1st and 2nd child of both instances to be the same, and the space between the 2nd and 3rd child of both instances to be the same.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean, can you show an image of the desired result?

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious would be to give each item a width, though if you can't or don't want, `flexbox` is not the best solution, a `grid` is.

As `CSS Grid` lacks good browser support, `CSS Table` doesn't, and is the perfect choice to accomplish this task.

```css
.component-container {
  display: table;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.component-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.component-row div {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.component-row div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20px;
}
.component-row div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-container">
  <div class="component-row">
    <div>looooooooooong</div>
    <div>mediummm</div>
    <div>short</div>
  </div>

  <div class="component-row">
    <div>short</div>
    <div>looooooooooong</div>
    <div>mediummm</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds really easy solution  but it is, just give a fixed width on a class and then place it on the `.component-row` childrens.

```css
.component-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.eq1 {
  width: 30%;
}
.eq2 {
  width: 20%;
}
.eq3 {
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-row">
  <div class="eq1" style="background-color: red;">looooooooooong</div>
  <div class="eq2" style="background-color: purple;">short</div>
  <div class="eq3" style="background-color: pink;">awdasdsdasad</div>
</div>

<div class="component-row">
  <div class="eq1" style="background-color: green;">looooooooooong</div>
  <div class="eq2" style="background-color: yellow;">srt</div>
  <div class="eq3" style="background-color: blue;">mediummm</div>
</div>
```